# Turning い-Adjectives into Adverbs

Tags: i-adjectives

I recently listened to a song named [アザトカワイイ](https://youtu.be/m-FRFhvM1EA) and I started asking myself about the grammar behind this one simple phrase.

According to this [site](https://hallyuplus.net/threads/hinatazaka46-%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B6%E3%83%88%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A4-azato-kawaii.35159/), the title means "Cunningly Cute" which makes sense because cunning in Japanese is あざとい, an い-Adjective.

But then I learned that you actually take the stem and add く to the adjective to make an い-Adjective into an Adverb.

I'm really confused right now **LMAO** Every input will be appreciated! Thanks in advance! ^~^

Comment: You're correct that the adverb is made by the stem + く. That being said, songs are a tricky subject: almost every rule can (and often will be) broken. Another example, a song named 「美しき残酷な世界」. Normally, you'd say 美しくて, but 美しき is an older, fancier way of saying (not used in commonly these days, though).

Comment: @Jak 美しき残酷な世界 or 美しい残酷な… are correct too in terms of grammar. く and くて are not the only way.

Comment: @user4092 I didn't mean to imply it was "incorrect" grammar-wise. Sorry if it came across like that. Only that it's not the common way, similar to using "yonder" or "thy" in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a compound word from the stem of あざとい combined with かわいい, in other words, one word.

Edit: It means to be cute in a manner that you boldly show yourself that way.

Comment: What does it mean though? :o